# How do I reset Symbol Lookup in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running Visual Studio Code 10.10.2 on a MacBook (MacOS Sierra 10.12.3) with the ms-vscode.cpptools C/C++ extension (0.10.3).

If I Cmd-click on a function name I usually get taken to the definition or declaration.  However, I'm getting an error "Unable to open 'xxx.h': File not found (absolute pathname)" where the pathname reported is old - I moved the file.  If I Option-F12 on the symbol instead, I see a list including old pre-move pathanmes and new post-move ones.

Clearly VSC hasn't refreshed its lookup table following my directory reorganisation, but I can't find a "force symbol table refresh" command.  Is there one, or do I have to hack a cache file somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look in `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage`

There should be a bunch of folders with random filenames. On my linux and Mac setups, the only things I've found in these folders are some sub folders called `ms-vscode.cpptools` but nothing else. So when I need to clear the symbols database, I just delete the `workspaceStorage` folder.

You should probably check that there is nothing else in there from other extensions - if there is, then you could try deleting the individual `ms-vscode.cpptools` folders.

Comment: I used grep to find files containing /Volumes/Workspaces/xxx/ which is the root of my project hierarchy.  It came back with 

Binary file ./User/workspaceStorage/3447e085e40f21546faf7d72bbc50de6/ms-vscode.cpptools/.browse.VC.db matches
Binary file ./User/workspaceStorage/3447e085e40f21546faf7d72bbc50de6/ms-vscode.cpptools/.browse.VC.db-wal matches

so I quit VSC, deleted those files, and ".browse.VC.db-shm" in the same directory too, then restarted VSC.

Monitoring ms-vscode.cpptools, I can see ".browse.VC.db" growing steadily, so I guess VSC is rescanning the workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting wrong matches when using `Go to Symbol in Editor [Ctrl+Shift+O]` on Windows 10, and as Nigel Scoot mentioned, deleting:
`C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage` directory made it.